# How to run a beam file generated by erlang

Tags: erlang, beam

I am a beginner in erlang. Please help me run an erlang program.

In the command line, I used this - `c(main).` to create a beam file. Now how do I run the program.
I am on windows.

```
% this is the hello world program I am trying to run
-module(main).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
   io:fwrite("Hello, world!\n").
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have written is a module. If compiled, then you will have to call the functions of this module to evaluate. Do like below, in the same command prompt where your Erlang Emulator(erl) is running...

```
Eshell V11.1.7  (abort with ^G)
1> main:start().
Hello, world!
ok
2>
```